# Find categories that have similar products - Low efficiency - Go

Tags: algorithm, performance, go, maps, slice

*Hello, sorry my english*

---

I have a list of categories and products associated with each category

`cats = [cat1, cat2, cat3]`

```
prod = {
 cat1 = [a, b, c]
 cat2 = [d, e, c]
 cat3 = [z, x, w]
}
```

#### What I want

```
{
    group1: [cat1, cat2]
    group2: [cat3]
}
```

I need to group the categories that share some of your products

Everything works for me, but I have **400,000** categories, it is not good to make two loops of that amount. My algorithm takes 4 days to finish

I just started with golang, does anyone have any idea how to deal with this problem? Thank you

- Groups can be of any size
- The quantity of products varies between categories
- The similarity percentage could change

---

```
func main() {

    cats, prod := getDataDB()

    for _, cat1 := range cats {

        for _, cat2 := range cats {

            result := percentageSimilarity(prod[cat1], prod[cat2])

            if result > 50{
                // save group
            }
        
        }
        
    }

}

func percentageSimilarity(a, b []string) int {

    sum := 0
    percentage := 0

    if len(a) > len(b) {

        for _, key := range a {

            if contains(b, key) {
                sum++
            }

        }

        percentage = sum * 100 / len(b)

    } else {

        for _, key := range b {

            if contains(a, key) {
                sum++
            }

        }

        percentage = sum * 100 / len(a)

    }

    return percentage

}

func contains(s []string, e string) bool {
    for _, a := range s {
        if a == e {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Are groups just pairs of categories, which have at least 50% similarity, or the disjoint sets where for each pair the similarity is high enough?

Comment: the size of the groups is undefined. It can be 1, 2, 3, 4 or more

Answer (score 1):

First, sort your categories from fewest products to most.

Next, create a [map](https://blog.golang.org/maps) from product to the array of categories that contains that product.

Now do something like this:

```
for each category
   create empty category_shared_products map from category to count of shared products
   for each product
      for each other_category containing that product
          add/increment category_shared_products[other_category]
   decide what to merge this category into (if anything)
```

There are a lot of details to get right.  But now instead of looking at every pair of categories, we are only looking at pairs of categories that actually share products in common.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to understand and apply it to the code.